# In angularjs application my external script is not getting loaded but if i have the script tag inside my html and embed the module it works fine

Tags: angularjs

Hello I created a small demo application in angularjs which requires ngRoute module.But my problem is when i include the js file reference inside the script tag it does not work. But if i am writing all the script code inside the script tags directly i.e. embedding all my module and controller in the main index.html file inside of the script tag it works fine. And when i include the js file reference in script tag, in the console I got:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=Demo&p1=Error%3A%2…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A179)

Comment: may be your missing the proper path while  including the js file reference inside the script tag

Comment: please share code snippets so the problem can be replicated.

Comment: thanks guys for your interest my problem was solved. probably the thing what i noticed was the order of placing the script tags i.e.      <script src = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> meaning our script file must be placed after we provide the cdn links for both angular and route .